# C# ftp client program create folder issue

Tags: c#, ftp, client, directory

I am writing a simple FTP client using C#. I did not find any samples which could create folder on FTP server, check whether a folder already exists on FTP server.

Any referred simple samples?

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried searching in google

[Heres one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/SimpleFTPDemo.aspx)